# How do you hide a list element based on a condition within a method?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Let's say I have an array of items that I loop through, and each of those items has its own conditions based on other parts of the application.

```
<template v-for="(item, index) in items">
  <li>
    <i :class="item.iconClass"></i>
    {{ item.name }}
    <strong :class="item.textClass"> {{ item.function }} </strong>
  </li>
</template>
```

```
items: [{
    iconClass: "fas fa-calendar",
    name: 'item1',
    textClass: "text_style",
    function: this.function1
  },
  {
    iconClass: "fas fa-user",
    name: 'item3',
    textClass: "text_style",
    function: this.function2
  }, {
    iconClass: "fas fa-clock",
    name: 'item3',
    textClass: "text_style",
    function: this.function2
  }
]
```

`item1` has a function that has some data from another array-

```
function1() {
  if (this.otherArray.otherItem) {
    return this.otherArray.otherItem
  }
}
```

Now, the data from the other array will not be shown if it does not exist (is false), but the icon and name for `item 1` will still be shown because they are not part of the conditional statement in the method.
So how do I rewrite this method so that it hides the entire item from the list if the condition is false?

**Remember,** `item 2` and `item 3` have their own set of conditions, so I cannot apply a v-if to the template. I need to target the items individually.

Comment: In your items object add property, maybe "show", with check if `otherArray` item is available. `show: !this.otherArray.otherItem`, then you can have `v-if="item.show"`. or skip that and use existing function property `v-if="!item.function()"`

Answer (score 0):

Add a `condition` property to each item of the array-

```
items: [{
    iconClass: "fas fa-calendar",
    name: 'item1',
    textClass: "text_style",
    function: this.function1,
    condition: this.otherArray && this.otherArray.otherItem
  },
  {
    iconClass: "fas fa-user",
    name: 'item3',
    textClass: "text_style",
    function: this.function2,
    condition: true // you can write your logic here
  }, {
    iconClass: "fas fa-clock",
    name: 'item3',
    textClass: "text_style",
    function: this.function2,
    condition: true // you can write your logic here
  }
]
```

And in the `template`, use this property to hide/show the item-

```
<template v-for="(item, index) in items">
  <li v-if="item.condition">
    <i :class="item.iconClass"></i>
    {{ item.name }}
    <strong :class="item.textClass"> {{ item.function }} </strong>
  </li>
</template>
```